# How to change the UIText view vertical scrollbar indicator color?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Are there any chances to change the `UITextView` vertical scroll bar indicator color? As per the requirement, I'm using the text view and want to change the color of the scroll bar indicator.

```
textView.isScrollEnabled = true
textView.showVerticalScrollIndicator = true
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code to update indicator color of `UIScrollView`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let verticalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 1)] as! UIImageView)

    verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 211/255.0, green: 138/255.0, blue: 252/255.0, alpha: 1).

}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. This is making bad assumptions about the private subview structure of the scroll view. This can easily change in a future iOS update. At least don't use a force-cast. Go through the subviews looking for one that actually is a UIImageView.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change black & white color from properties of UITextView

[image]

**1 .Add UIScrollViewDelegate**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end
```

**2. Add scrollViewDidScroll in implementation section**

and if you have to change new color so you have to use

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
        let verticalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 1)] as! UIImageView)
        verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        let horizontalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 2)] as! UIImageView)
        horizontalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
   }
```